# Get first N records from stored procedure result set in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Is there is any solution / query to get first N records from stored procedure result without retrieving the whole result set?

Consider my stored procedure returns 3 million rows, and I just want the first 10 rows from it.

Comment: You need to write this within the procedure not outside the procedure.

Comment: Create temp table, execute SP and insert into temp table, the filter from it.
But this consume lots of resources.

Comment: Yes. that is my point to. It consume lots of resource. I looking for an optimized way to achieve it. @SurajKumar i am in need to do this outside the stored procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`TOP`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp) clause to achieve it

**Syntax**

```
SELECT TOP number|percent column_name(s) 
FROM table_name 
WHERE condition;
```

Let's say that you have `Your_stored_procedure` return list of users

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Your_stored_procedure
AS
    SELECT UserId, UserName
    FROM yourtable
GO;
```

At here, you need to create temp table to store value from stored procedure

```
-- Check result
CREATE TABLE #TempTable 
(
    UserId          INT,
    UserName        varchar(100),
)
INSERT INTO #TempTable(UserId, UserName) 
EXEC Your_stored_procedure
```

Then you can get the result like this way

```
SELECT TOP 10 UserId, UserName
FROM #TempTable 
ORDER BY UserId -- As @Squirrel's comment, TOP should come with ORDER BY
```

**Note**

You should make sure that the number of columns in your table according to the structure of the stored procedure.

**Updated**

As @Vinod Kumar's  comment, you can also achieve it by using [OPENQUERY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openquery-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) like below

```
SELECT top 1 * FROM OPENQUERY ([MyServer], 'EXEC [VinodTest].[dbo].[tblAuthorsLarge] year = 2014')
```

Comment: This will work for tables not for stored procedures.

Comment: `TOP` should come with`ORDER BY`

Comment: No @Phong. I am not suppose to do anything inside stored procedure.

Comment: I've just updated my answer. Please take a look at.  @Vinod Kumar

Comment: @Phong in this method i am forced to extract all the data from stored procedure to temptable and from temptable i am getting n records. If the stored procedure is very large i have to wait till extracting all data to temp table to get first 3 records. can you suggest me another optimized way to do it?

Comment: There is no way unless you modify your stored procedure (get top numbers of rows as you wish). You should know the difference between `Function` and `Stored Procedure`.  **A select statement can have a function call. <--->  A select statement can't have a procedure call.**

Comment: @Phong, I am not supposed to do any changes in the stored procedure. That's why i didn't accepted your answer. i gone openquery statement in SQL server and seems it meets my required solution

Comment: @Phong --  My  Query : 
 SELECT top 1 *
FROM OPENQUERY ([MyServer],
'EXEC [VinodTest].[dbo].[tblAuthorsLarge]
  year = 2014') --- I am getting only first record here and am able to retrieve result very quickly even for large data set.

Comment: Great idea. Do you need I update my answer to help other people in the future?

Comment: Yes @Phong. Please do it. :-)

Comment: Updated, Please check it @Vinod Kumar

Answer (score 2):

The best approach would be to alter your stored procedure to be able to include a parameter for the TOP filter.

However, you could also use

```
SET ROWCOUNT 10
EXEC MyProc
```

Be careful to reset the value of [ROWCOUNT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-rowcount-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) afterwards otherwise you may impact other queries.

The downside is that you cannot control the order of the rows.  I also haven't tested with such a large result set to identify whether this does reduce resource consumption enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Fetch next` clause. Please refer [this](https://www.dofactory.com/sql/order-by-offset-fetch) for more information.

```
 SELECT column-names
  FROM table-name
 ORDER BY column-names
OFFSET n ROWS
 FETCH NEXT m ROWS ONLY
```